# Azure DevOps Code Review email does not list files that are to be reviewed

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-code-review

When I get a code review from another person, sometimes the code review states the project name and list the files that are contained in the review. More often than not, it just says none. (please see red box in the image below)

Unless the person gives a good title, it can be difficult to know which project I need to review.
When I open the review, all of the files show up and everything works just fine.
Its only the email that seems to be the issue.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce above issue. It seems that the problem resides in azure devops server.

You can report this problem to microsoft development team. Hope they will look into this issue and provide a fix soon.

Click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to report a problem(Click Report a problem and choose Azure devops or Azure devops server if you are using on-premise server).

[image]